# Можно ли заключить в одни кавычки названия нескольких кнопок

Tags: кавычки

Если существует инструкция для пользователя перейти в раздел меню, а кнопки не выделяются жирным шрифтом, можем ли мы вместо заключения каждой кнопки в кавычки, поставить кавычки в начале и в конце?

Например:

Нажмите «Профиль > Настройки > Пароль»

Comment: Зачем название кнопки или опции заключать в кавычки? Чтобы не загромождать строку, достаточно использовать запись с Прописной или ПРОПИСЬЮ.